# Launchpad keeps moving my apps around every time a new app is installed

Tags: launchpad

What it says on the tin.

I have my apps organised in folders in Launchpad. However, whenever a new app is installed most of the stuff in the last folder gets put in a new folder, which Launch Pad automatically names based on the type of apps they are; whether the new app is put there as well or simply placed outside all folders depends on the type of app it is. Stuff in folders other than the last one are not moved. (Running macOS 13.4.)

Before installing a new app:
[image]

After installing a new app:
[image]

I'd obviously like this to stop. What's going on? How can I stop it?

Thanks in advance.